# Map with position index

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Which collection would satisfy the following test program:

```
public class TestOrderedList {

  // The class I'm looking for:
  MapWithIndex<String,Person> ol = new MapWithIndex<String, Person>();

  // class Person left out for brevity

  public TestOrderedList() {

    Person benny = new Person("Benny");
    Person charles = new Person("Charles");
    Person alvin = new Person("Alvin");
    Person calvin = new Person("Calvin");

    ol.put("Benny", benny);     // should return 0
    ol.put("Charles", charles); // should return 1
    ol.put("Alvin", alvin);     // should return 0
    ol.put("Calvin", calvin);   // should return 2

    int index = ol.findIndex("Benny"); // should return 1 
    Person adam = new Person("Adam");
    ol.put("Adam", adam);              // should return 0 (new pos)
    index = ol.findIndex("Benny");     // should return 2
    ol.remove("Alvin");                // should return 1 (existing pos)
    index = ol.findIndex("Benny");     // should return 1
  }
}
```

The collection does not have to be implementing any particular interface, or be convertible to another collection (however of that is possible it would be nice).

It does not have to be thread safe, but if it is.... good!

Returning -1 when not found or error situation is OK.

The purpose of the collection is that I quickly need to know at which position a newly inserted record was put in. Also I want to look up at what position a record exists.

The collection doesn't need to support duplicate keys.

--- update ----

I went with the ArrayList solution, where I keep it sorted by doing a binary lookup before inserting (to get the index where it should be inserted). This way the position in the list always correspond to the row number (in the table that that is synced with this list). It's fast and simple. I'm sure there must exists a more robust implementation than mine though?!?!

Comment: This structure is really strange because it returns the "position" of the inserted element but that position is not fixed. A structure like this would never be thread safe. Probably you need to explain what you are doing.

Comment: OK I can add that it does not have to be thread safe in this case. But the "put" method should return the position that the record was inserted in at that moment.

Comment: Possibly an indexable SkipList would fit the bill.  There's not one in the JDK, although ConcurrentSkipListMap might be close.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array with a binary search implementation of "find", the problem is that with an array it's expensive to add/remove items.  An [indexable skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist) would be more amenable to growing/shrinking, with the same average case lookup as an array, however arrays have a better worst-case lookup and may also have better cache performance.  If you're expecting frequent adds/deletes then I'd say use an indexable skip list, if they're rare then use an array.  There may also be some way to buffer the adds/deletes for the array to get better amortized performance, but offhand I don't know how you'd do this.

Comment: Maybe you should cite me :)

Comment: @spudone My bad, I was typing that out at the same time as you.  Consider yourself cited :)

Comment: No worries I'm just messing around.  If you find a good implementation (with the indexable option) in Java, please post it!

Comment: Apache Commons also has a TreeList counterpart to the JDK's TreeMap, but there's no indexable version of the map afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [linkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to ensure order and keep their index on a seperate map implementation.

Comment: can you elaborate on how I get the position after an insert?

Comment: Implement it so that you record the positions seperately e.g. two maps one for the objects and one for the positions

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Map;  
import java.util.Set;  
import java.util.TreeMap;  

public class MySortMap {


// The class I'm looking for:
  Map<String,Person> ol = new TreeMap<String, Person>();

  // class Person left out for brevity

  public void TestOrderedList() {

    Person benny = new Person("Benny");
    Person charles = new Person("Charles");
    Person alvin = new Person("Alvin");
    Person calvin = new Person("Calvin");

    ol.put("Benny", benny);     // should return 0
    ol.put("Charles", charles); // should return 1
    ol.put("Alvin", alvin);     // should return 0
    ol.put("Calvin", calvin);   // should return 2

    int index = getIndex(ol.keySet(), "Benny"); // should return 1 
    System.out.println("expected 1, index="  + index);
    Person adam = new Person("Adam");
    ol.put("Adam", adam);              // should return 0 (new pos)
    index = getIndex(ol.keySet(), "Benny");     // should return 2
    System.out.println("expected 2, index="  + index);
    ol.remove("Alvin");                // should return 1 (existing pos)
    index = getIndex(ol.keySet(), "Benny");     // should return 1
    System.out.println("expected 1, index="  + index);

  } 

  private int getIndex(Set<String> paramSet, String paramSearchStr) {
      int result = -1;
      for (String strSetValue : paramSet) {
        result++;
        if (strSetValue.equals(paramSearchStr)) {
            return result;
        }
    }
      return -1;
  }
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MySortMap mySortMap = new MySortMap();
    mySortMap.TestOrderedList();
}

    class Person {
        public Person(String paramPerson) {

        }
    }
}

RESULT:  
expected 1, index=1  
expected 2, index=2  
expected 1, index=1
```

Comment: +1 for working code! Sequential search in getIndex was not what I hoped for but I guess it works in small sets and with limited update frequencies.

Comment: If you use list you can use the indexOf method to get the index.